# Command line to permanently get access to folder

Tags: command-line, windows-10, icacls

**UPDATE**
While I was able to use the method described in accepted answer once it failed a second time or was just giving too much trouble.

Searching further I found [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/) by Helge Klein which is far far superior and does exactly what is needed.

---

I cannot access certain folders e.g. `c:\Program Files\WindowsApps`. Via command line I get an error of "**Access is denied**" and via Windows Explorer I get a pop up a dialog box stating "**You don't currently have permission to access this folder**"

[image]

Clicking on **Continue** gives me access, but I would like to grant myself access using the command line; so that my scripts do not run into this problem running under the same security context.

I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/48704cce-6234-4807-be2a-67b64240cec8/you-dont-currently-have-permission-to-access-this-folder-click-continue-to-permanently-get-access?forum=w7itprosecurity) question on Microsoft Technet but I couldn't get it to work. Note that I am already running Powershell as administrator.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> icacls "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" /grant i063510:F /inheritance:e
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> icacls "C:\Program Files" /grant i063510:F /inheritance:e
C:\Program Files: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

If it matters, I am using **Windows 10 upgraded from Windows 8.1**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ### **You don't currently have permission to access this folder**

Try [ICACLS](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) and/or [TAKEOWN](http://ss64.com/nt/takeown.html) with the below syntax against the folder with the username as needed.

Try just the *ICACLS commands first and if that doesn't resolve*, run the *TAKEOWN commands and then run the ICACLS commands* again.

---

### **[ICACLS](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) Commands**

- <sup>**Grant explicit full control access to this folder to all beneath subfolders, and files leaving all inherited permissions in place and continue on error**</sup>

  > ```
  > ICACLS "<FolderPath>" /INHERITANCE:e /GRANT:r <UserName>:(F) /T /C
  > ```
- <sup>**Grant explicit modify access to this folder to all beneath subfolders, and files leaving all inherited permissions in place and continue on error**</sup>

  > ```
  > ICACLS "<FolderPath>" /INHERITANCE:e /GRANT:r "<UserName>":(M) /T /C
  > ```
- <sup>**Change the owner of this folder and all beneath subfolders and files and continue on error**</sup>

  > ```
  > ICACLS "<FolderPath>" /SETOWNER "<UserName>" /T /C
  > ```

---

### **[TAKEOWN](http://ss64.com/nt/takeown.html) Commands**

- <sup>**Run this as the account which you want to grant ownership to, and it'll be changed to the owner of the folder and all beneath subfolders and files**</sup>

  > ```
  > TAKEOWN /F "<FolderPath>" /R /D Y
  > ```

Comment: Thanks. I want to avoid `TAKEOWN` / `SETOWNER`. I am assuming that it changes the owner and Windows Explorer only assigns permission.

Comment: Can you confirm if just the `ICACLS "<FolderPath>" /INHERITANCE:e /GRANT:r "<UserName>":(OI)(CI)(X,M,F) /T /C` will then give you the expected result? I'll update my answer with more detail if so.

Comment: You have to take ownership of that folder if you want permissions to that specific folder, any other folder, you could avoid taking ownership

Comment: This works for me: `ICACLS "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" /INHERITANCE:e /GRANT:r i063510:F /T /C`. Thanks for your help. @Ramhound I could not understand from your comment when I do or do not need to take ownership.

Comment: @MiserableVariable I just updated my answer with further detail as well.