# Cant Grant Security Permissions for Certain Files that in Folders

Tags: windows, security, permissions, file-permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

I am System Administrator on Windows Server 2008 R2.
When i try to grant Security Permissions to folders that on the server, some folders successfully got the permissions (along with error display that "**Access Denied**" Even though i System Administrator) while the other folders that **in** that folder just dont get them.
Same thing happens to files that in those folders.

We try to figure this out, maybe someone gave any **DENY** permission, or maybe user ownership blocks it, but we did not succeed.

The only way that work for me way: to go **each** folder and file and grant it local administrator ownership, and then i can grant Security Permissions.
But, it is not the way its should be.

Comment: you could try `Top Most Folder > Properties > Security > Advanced` there should be a checkbox on the bottom called something like `Replace all authorization entries for subordinate objects with inheritable authorization entries from this object`. Check this box and hit OK. Sadly I don't have a 2008 R2 to test this, but it's like this on Server 2012 R2

Comment: That clear all of the permissions we had before but still, it was not effecting inside files

Comment: Consider trying the steps I listed in this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1100532/command-line-to-permanently-get-access-to-folder/1100591#1100591

Comment: Look into the recursive/silent/forced usage of the `Takeown` command. If you run that as domain admin and grant ownership to domain admin it could work.

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to effect all other security permission that within the folders

Comment: As per the link I provided (above), note the ICACLS command notes where it's states "*~leaving all inherited permissions in place*" so as per "*i dont want to effect all other security permission that within the folders*", this will leave all inherited permissions in place and not break inheritance. The other commands will set the owner and take ownership but will not break any inherited ACL NTSF permissions. Start with a small test if possible and be sure you have full backups as well in your cannot test beforehand. This should be easy to test and commands needed are there (above comment).

Comment: We reached the Administrator who install the system and he gave us his credentials for ownership of those folders. It solve it.